# Migrate MS Access Data into Oracle DB

Tags: spatial-database, oracle-dbms, metadata, personal-geodatabase

I was sent some old MS Access files that contained survey data and served as a "file geodatabase".

I want to import these to my Oracle Database with it maintaining "geometric" sense and meaning.

I am relatively new to this and want to know if there is a way to proof my data/format when i do these imports.

In addition to these files forming part of a feature class, it has some crucial metadata about the survey that needs to be stored in our enterprise database.

Comment: The correct terminology for your "file geodatabase" stored in MS Access is a Personal Geodatabase (which is quite distinct from a File Geodatabase that is stored as a folder of proprietary format files).

Comment: I would be thinking this would need to be done in ArcCatalog or OGR2OGR to maintain/translate the geometry from pGDB to Oracle Geometry type. Do you have Esri SDE on your Oracle? QGIS should read personal geodatabase format and allow you to view the contents spatially - you can even export to shapefile but be aware that shapefile has serious limitations that may cause problems later.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I am leaning towards of using the ArcCatalog instead. Any python scripts that you guys would recommend me to take a look at?